# Using jquery handler in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, backbone.js

I have been using Angular for a bit and really find myself much more efficient and produce many few lines of code than I did in Backbone and jquery.  However, I work with other developers that are primary creating in Backbon/jquery components/controls we all share.  Since these are complex components/controls that I cannot rewrite in Angular I need to find a way to use them from within Angular.

In the specific case I am dealing with a control that create a dialog that lets users created entries in a series of help request systems or log bugs.  This code is working in a number of applications.  Here is a simple example :

```
    <div class="foo">Help</div>
```

And then the handler.

```
    $(".foo").ShowHelp({project:"myproject", app:"MyApp"});
```

Note "foo" is used to position the dialog.

In Angular I tried to create add an ng-click directive and in my controller handle the click, but ShowHelp is not invoked.  This is the angular code:

```
    <div class="foo" ng-click="doShowHelp()">Help</div>
```

In the controller I have

```
   $scope.doShowHelp = function() {
        console.log("in doShowHelp");
        $(".foo").ShowHelp({project:"myproject", app:"MyApp"});
   };
```

I see the log message in the console, but nothing seems to happen.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you throw a basic version in a plunker or fiddle? It's probably an easy fix, but it would help to see more code.

Comment: Is *"`("foo")`"* actually *"`(".foo")`"* in your code?

Comment: what does `$(".foo").ShowHelp()` do?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the dot in front of the "foo" selector

Try

$(".foo").ShowHelp({project:"myproject", app:"MyApp"});

Comment: Opps.  The leading dot is there in the real code.  To aggressive with the cut/paste.  I updated the sample.

Answer (score 0):

Most of all directives has function 'link', with different params, one of them is DOM element of currect directive. Something like this:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  element.ShowHelp({project:"myproject", app:"MyApp"});
  ...
}
```

Comment: That looks interesting.  How would I wire up the directive so that when the user clicked on the element ShowHelp() is invoked?

Comment: No, it will be invoked after compiling of DOM